# Webview plugin unable to open the app to the full size of screen?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutterwebviewplugin

I'm using flutter's flutter_webview_plugin in my app and it is working fine with every mobile except the phone with a notch like an iPhone X. I'm getting white spaces on top and bottom, is there any way to resolve it?[This is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6U9Zm.jpg)

Comment: I have the exact same issue, has this been solved? Using flutter_webview_plugin too.

Comment: The best thing you can do is make the notch area transparent so it will show the clock and battery icon. Nothing else. For me I made the background black for my website and made the whole top notch transparent which made it look like a clean black background